# Install GMP plugin php

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, gmp

I have a laravel project build  inside Docker.

I want to install plugin GMP in php.

Here is my code.

```
FROM industrydigital/php-nginx:1.2.0

ARG API_VERSION
ARG API_BUILD
ARG GIT_REVISION

ENV API_VERSION=$API_VERSION
ENV API_BUILD=$API_BUILD
ENV GIT_REVISION=$GIT_REVISION

COPY ./src /var/www/html
COPY ./docker/assets/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/assets/php.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini

USER root
RUN set -eu \
&& cd /var/www/html \
&& rm -f public/index.html \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/app/public \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/temp \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/views \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/cache \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/sessions \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/logs \
&& find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \; \
&& find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \; \
&& chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache \
&& chmod +x artisan \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/.config/psysh \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.config/psysh \
&& chmod 750 /var/www/.config/psysh \
&& mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/cache/nginx \
&& mkdir -p /var/secrets \
&& chown -R root:www-data /var/secrets \
&& chmod -R 750 /var/secrets

WORKDIR "/var/www/html"

# Install the gmp and mcrypt extensions
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y libgmp-dev re2c libmhash-dev libmcrypt-dev file
RUN ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/gmp.h /usr/local/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gmp 
RUN docker-php-ext-install gmp

VOLUME ["/var/www/html/storage", "/var/www/html/bootstrap/cache", "/var/cache/nginx", 
 "/var/secrets"]
```

But this throws

> /bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-configure: not found
> The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-configure gmp' returned a non-zero code: 127

Can someone please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd debug this by:

1. Creating the docker image with just this:

```
FROM industrydigital/php-nginx:1.2.0

ARG API_VERSION
ARG API_BUILD
ARG GIT_REVISION

ENV API_VERSION=$API_VERSION
ENV API_BUILD=$API_BUILD
ENV GIT_REVISION=$GIT_REVISION

COPY ./src /var/www/html
COPY ./docker/assets/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/assets/php.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini

USER root
RUN set -eu \
&& cd /var/www/html \
&& rm -f public/index.html \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/app/public \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/temp \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/views \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/cache \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/framework/sessions \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/html/storage/logs \
&& find . -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \; \
&& find . -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \; \
&& chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/storage \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache \
&& chmod +x artisan \
&& mkdir -p /var/www/.config/psysh \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/.config/psysh \
&& chmod 750 /var/www/.config/psysh \
&& mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data /var/cache/nginx \
&& mkdir -p /var/secrets \
&& chown -R root:www-data /var/secrets \
&& chmod -R 750 /var/secrets
```

2. Boot a container based on the image
3. SSH into that new container (https://linuxhandbook.com/ssh-into-container/)
4. Continue the steps manually, if you run into errors you will see the full error trace in the terminal
5. Keep the same session open until you solve it
6. Copy the commands that you need from `.bash_history` in the container and rewrite the docker build accordingly